# How to implement busy indicator (Spinner or loading image or processing icon)

Tags: custom-button

I need to implement busy indicator (Spinner or loading image or processing icon) on a custom button present in a standard page layout while some validation process runs in background.I have custom button on click javascript execution.Below are the javascript code I am currently using.I cannot use actition status tag as its not a visual force page.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")}

var receiverActivation = '{!Receiver_Activation__c.Id}';

var strQuery = "SELECT Id, RID__c, Status__c FROM Receiver_Activation_Line_Item__c WHERE Receiver_Activation__c = '" + receiverActivation + "'";

var queryResult = sforce.connection.query(strQuery);
var records = queryResult.getArray("records");

var newRecords = [];

for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    var statusUpdate = new sforce.SObject("Receiver_Activation_Line_Item__c");
    statusUpdate.Id = records[i].Id;

    if (records[i].get("Status__c") == "In Transit") {
        statusUpdate.Status__c = "Activated";
        newRecords.push(statusUpdate);
    }
}

result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords);

window.location.reload();
```

Comment: for those interested, Keir Bowden's book `Visualforce Development Cookbook` covers this as a recipe along with dozens of other cool things you can do to make VF pages 'better'

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a background element and an image and dynamically append them to the DOM, then show them and hide them before and after the code has run accordingly. This can be your starting point:

```
var div, img;

if (document.getElementById('myDiv') && document.getElementById('myImg'))
{
    div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    img = document.getElementById('myImg');
    div.style.display = 'block';
    img.style.display = 'block';
}
else
{
    // Create a background and show the image on top
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'myDiv';
    div.style.width = '100%';
    div.style.height = '100%';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.top = '0';
    div.style.left = '0';
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    div.style.opacity = '0.5';
    div.style.zIndex = '100';
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    img = document.createElement('img');
    img.id = 'myImg';
    img.src = 'https://umps1t4.salesforce.com/umps/UMPSWidget_184/images/spinner_16_174.gif'; // your spinner gif
    img.style.position = 'absolute';
    img.style.top = '50%';
    img.style.left = '50%';
    img.style.zIndex = '101';
    div.appendChild(img);
}

// your code 


// Hide the image and the background upon completion
div.style.display = 'none';
img.style.display = 'none';
```